# How to unparent children and keep them (where they are)?

Tags: parent

So, I don't really know how to formulate the problem to begin with, so here's a picture. The object in the middle is child of the two circles, with instancing set to vertices. How can I unparent the objects and keep the ones on the vertices where they are?

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the circles, go to *Object > Apply > Make Instances Real* or press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type "Make instances real"

Comment: Booyah! Thank you.